# Perl Script throwing internal error on godaddy shared hosting

Tags: perl, cpanel

I am using code below in the very lines if the script.   but it shows 500 internal error.

```
#!/usr/bin/perlml
    
     
    use HTML::Parser;
    
    print "Content-Type: text/html\n\nStatus: 200 OK\n";
    
    &ReadParse(*input);
    $lpm         = HTML::Parser::encode($input{'lpm'});
    $pressure    = HTML::Parser::encode($input{'pressure'});
    $units       = HTML::Parser::encode($input{'units'});
    $material    = HTML::Parser::encode($input{'material'});
    $media       = HTML::Parser::encode($input{'media'});
```

Comment: Check the logs, they should contain the actual Perl error.

Comment: file has no execute permission: (/ inquiry_m.pl). i updated the permission to 777 but still the same error.

Comment: It will always say there was an error to the browser. Keep reading the logs.

Comment: Don't give your Perl script 777 permissions! That's a huge security risk. It should be 755. Are you sure /usr/bin/perlml exists on the server? I suspect it does not.